# How to extract value betwen two string using regex?

Tags: regex

Here is the demo String:

> beforeValueAfter

Assume that I know the value I want is between "before" and "After"
I want to extact the "Value" using the regex....

> pervious909078375639355544after

Assume that I know the value I want is between "pervious90907" and "55544after"
I want to extact the "83756393" using the regex....

thx in advance.

Comment: you can just do a string substitution on "pervious90907" and "55544after". you will be left with the value you want. no need regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends on two things:

- If you know *exactly* what the value consists of (if you know it will be digits, etc., it makes it easier).  If it could be anything, the answer is a little harder.
- If your system is greedy/ungreedy by default, it affects the way you'd set up the expression.  I will assume it is greedy by default.

If it can be anything (the ? will be needed to toggle the `.*` to ungreedy because "`.*`" also matches "After":

```
/before(.*?)After/
```

If you know it is digits:

```
/before(\d*)After
```

If it could be any word characters (0-9, a-z, A-Z, _):

```
/before(\w*?)After
```

Comment: `\w` contains more word character than just `0`-`9`, `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z` and `_`.

Comment: @Gumbo, depends on the platform you are using

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
pervious90907(.*?)55544after
```

That will get you the shortest string (note the non-greedy `*?` quantifier) between `pervious90907` and `55544after`.

Comment: If I want to limited the result is digit only, what can I do?

Comment: Replace the `.` with `[0-9]`, so `[0-9]*?`.

Comment: @Tattat: \d

See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be like this:

```
previous([0-9]*)after
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bash-3.2$ echo pervious909078375639355544after | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /pervious90907(.*)55544after/'
83756393
```