# Extract a complex String from between two Strings

Tags: java, regex

I have a String which contains the following sub string:

`[Qual:3] [Text:PIX 1252471471953/YHYF/PPP121.40/10RTY10/NOLXX08X1] [Elem:123]`

I'd like to extract the part between `[Text:` and `]` i.e. `PIX 1252471471953/YHYF/PPP121.40/10RTY10/NOLXX08X1`.

How do I do this?

Comment: `\\[Text:(.*)\\].*` off the top of my head

Comment: Use `String.substring(int, int)` and `String.indexOf(String, int)`

Comment: I've been trying variations on the suggestions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216601/how-to-extract-value-betwen-two-string-using-regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[Text:(.*?)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("[Qual:3] [Text:PIX 1252471471953/YHYF/PPP121.40/10RTY10/NOLXX08X1] [Elem:123]");
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Gives:

```
PIX 1252471471953/YHYF/PPP121.40/10RTY10/NOLXX08X1
```

The `\\[` and `\\]` are to escape the brackets, which are special characters in regexes. The `.*?` is a non-greedy quantifier, so it stops gobbling up characters when it reaches the closing bracket. This part of the regex is given inside a capturing group `()`, which you can access with `m.group(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following string as the regex:

```
"\\[Text:(.*?)\\]"
```

The first capture group will give you exactly the substring you want.

The non-greedy match (`.*?`) is required to make it stop at the first `]` rather than also including `[Elem:123]`.

Comment: Beat me to it! +1. @mip, note the difference between `.*?` and `.*`. One of the commenters suggested `.*`, but that doesn't work; it doesn't stop where it should.

Answer (score 0):

```
String.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

Returns a new string that is a substring of this string.

You could use this to remove the start and end of the string,

or....

You could use

```
String.indexOf(String str)
```

To get the index of the start and end of the match and copy the contents to a new result string.

You could use

```
String.matches(String regex)
```

However writing regular expressions can get difficult,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `"\\[Text:(.*?)\\]"`, as others have suggested, I'd go one step further and use lookarounds to filter out the text you don't want:

`(?<=\\[Text:).*?(?=\\])`

This will match exactly the text you want without having to select a capturing group.

Comment: thanks for that. What would the Java look like? Would I replace `m.find` and `m.group(1)`?